# In British English, is there a difference between a match and fixture in football?

Tags: british-english, sports

Or are they synonyms?
My guess is that fixtures are matches that haven't been played yet...

Comment: In the US, a 'match' is a common term in sports for a or some part of a meeting of teams. In the US, a'fixture' has absolutely nothing to do with sports (it is used mostly in the context 'electrical' or 'light fixture'. Is your usage in terms of UK English?

Comment: @Rathony Excellent... a new word (well, usage) for me then. Looking it up online, they say mostly 'British: an event that takes place regularly', so I think newer in the US, also 'fixture' is definitely used in sports but can easily be used elsewhere (whereas 'match' is mostly entirely sports, if you include chess as a sport).

Comment: @Mitch- yeah I’ve never heard that usage either.  It sounds like ***schedule*** to me.

Comment: To address the question (if not answering it) - in the UK, *fixture* does commonly refer to a *scheduled* future match. However, it is also used to *connect* previous similar events. During play, a commentator might say *"Arsenal haven't scored in this fixture since 2012"* - meaning "against the same opposition, at the same venue". The phrase "Walcott has been poor in this match" does not mean the same thing as "Walcott has been poor in this fixture."

Comment: @Rathony That site is based in Malta, and can be expected to use BrEnglish, but *fixture* is not used in this sense in US English. The text appears on the page as *NBA 2015/2016 Schedule, NBA 2015/2016 Fixtures, Upcoming Matches* which is clearly keyword stuffing (as *matches* isn't used for NBA basketball games, either). Compare [NBA.com results for *schedule*](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Anba.com+%222015-16%20schedule%22) vs. [NBA.com results for *fixture*](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Anba.com+%222015-16%20fixture%22).

Answer (score 3):

They are synonyms but not perfect synonyms. In other words the meanings overlap. Which should be used is determined by context.

---

In the US, a fixture is a date rather than a match.

> fixture
>   a settled date or time especially for a sporting or festive
>   event; also :  such an event especially as a regularly scheduled
>   affair
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixture)

However your question uses the ***british english*** tag so:

In Britain it would be possible to say that team X played a number of fixtures.

> fixture
>   2. BRITISH a sporting event arranged to take place on a particular date. "the team's last away fixture of the season"
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fixture)

Comment: I have never heard the term *fixture* used in this sense in American English. Not in any newspaper, magazine, website, or on any broadcast.

Comment: @Robusto, I gave two senses--one US and one British. Which are you referring to? Are you disagreeing with anything in my answer? I'm not sure what your comment adds. Could you elucidate? thanks.  P.S. Note that the question is tagged 'british english' so I didn't need to mention US usage -- I did so simply as added information. Have I incorrectly represented the US point of view?

Comment: *Pace* M-W, I don't think the term **fixture** has much, if any, currency in the US. I've never heard it. Perhaps one might hear the term on a soccer match on TV, where one of the announcers or "color commentators" is British.  (It was I who added the British English tag.)

Comment: You'll often hear Britishisms like "well up!" on the pitch at US soccer matches, but that is very self-conscious emulation which sometimes involves an imitation Geordie accent :)

Comment: "Fixture" is used in court tennis in the U.S. to mean a tournament that is played every year -- e.g., the Anne Boleyn, a handicap tournament for women players, first prize a miniature steel axe.  (Should be a sword, of course.)   (court tennis is jeu de paume in France, real tennis in the UK and Australia).  It is played mainly by Anglophiles.

Comment: The link may show it, but my experience does not. And my experience in American sports is pretty robust.

Comment: @Rathony: Sky is a venue for British sports. I rest my case.

Comment: What they choose to cover is not the issue. The issue is the audience they cover it for.

Comment: Fixture in this context is definitely never used in American English, and nowhere commonly in American sporting language. The answer immediately above is wrong for US English, and does not help to explain the usage in British English, and therefore should be booted altogether. The 4th comment directly beneath the question itself, by @JHCL, appears to have the best answer to this question.